# MPMoviePlayer crashes in device but works fine in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

In my app i am playing a video using the following code.

```
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:downloadURL];

    mMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:myURL];

    if (mMoviePlayer) {
        [self initMoviePlayer];
        [mMoviePlayer play];
    }
```

This code is working fine in simulator, but when i test it in device it is giving "BAD_ACCESS" error. Device is not at all sending the request to video.

Can some one help me with this..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this code. The bug is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

`BAD_ACCESS` generally points to memory management issues: you're trying to access an object that has been deallocated. If you're sure that the crash is happening on the above line, double check that `safeURL` exists at that point. If it does, you're going to have to post more code for us to give you any pointers.

Comment: @nboja--The simulator is not a perfect replica of the device, especially when it comes to matters of memory allocation.